# Putting Distance Matrix result into an existing array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm attempting to simply get the distance from a user a set of locations are. The locations are called from a database earlier in the code. The "places" array has 3 entries into it, each of which contains some information and a "distance" and "duration" field which are both set to 0 as a placeholder. I am trying to iterate through the DistanceMatrix "distance.text" and "duration.text" results and add them to the corresponding object's "distance" and "duration" fields, but I either can't use places[i] in the callback function or, if I try to add the values outside of the callback, it loses the returned values.

```
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();//request distance matrix
    var outputdiv = document.getElementById('info');

    for (var i=1;i<places.length;i++){
        var goto = new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng);
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                origins: [foundlatlng],
                destinations: [goto],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false,
              }, callback);//end service.getdistancematrix()

                function callback(response, status) {
                var distancefield = distancefield;
                  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    var origins = response.originAddresses;
                    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
                    var results = response.rows[0].elements;

                      for (var r = 0; r < results.length; r++) {
                        var element = results[r];
                        var distancetext = element.distance.text;
                        var durationtext = element.duration.text;
                        var to = destinations[r];
                      }//end for r

                  }//end if status=ok
                }//end callback

    };//end for i
    console.log(places);
```

`foundlatlng` is the coordinates found by the GPS, represented as a google.maps.LatLng. It's from earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Distance Matrix call is asynchronous, you need to update your array and use the returned values inside the callback function.

(The console.log(places) will always run before the date comes back)

I don't see any code in your question to add the returned data to your "places" array, that should be in the callback routine, all you are doing right now is creating variables in the local scope which won't be available once the callback function exits.

It also looks like you aren't taking advantage of the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DistanceMatrixService) Service's ability to take multiple origins and destinations and return the driving distance between them in a single call.  The way your posted code uses it is inefficient and only returns a single result at a time (if you are going to do that, you might as well use the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService)).

[working example with made up data](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_distanceMatrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way to do it:

```
var placesIndex = 0;
calculateDistance();

function calculateDistance(response,status){

  if(response) {
    var distancefield = distancefield;
    if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var place = places[placesIndex]; // use this in your calculations
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var results = response.rows[0].elements;

      for (var r = 0; r < results.length; r++) {
        var element = results[r];
        var distancetext = element.distance.text;
        var durationtext = element.duration.text;
        var to = destinations[r];
      }//end for r
    }//end if status=ok
  }

  if(placesIndex < places.length) {
    var goto = new google.maps.LatLng(places[placesIndex].lat, places[placesIndex].lng);

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
        origins: [foundlatlng],
        destinations: [goto],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false,
      }, calculateDistance);//end service.getdistancematrix()

    placesIndex ++;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for this response. I'm going to try requesting them all as a single response, but this method could also work in that situation.

Comment: I combined Geocodezip's suggestions with your parsing technique and it worked. Thank you so much for the suggestion on how to iterate through the indexes!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your suggestions!!! Here is the code:

```
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();//request distance matrix from the Googleplex
    var outputdiv = document.getElementById('info');
    var destArray = [<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM places");
        foreach($result as $key => $value){echo "'" . $value['address'] . "',"; };?>];

            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                origins: [foundlatlng],
                destinations: destArray,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false,
              }, callback);//end service.getdistancematrix()

                function callback(response, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    var origins = response.originAddresses;
                    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
                    console.log(response);
                    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                        var element = results[j];
                        var distance = element.distance.text;
                        var duration = element.duration.text;
                        var from = origins[i];
                        var to = destinations[j];
                        generateArray(to, destinations, distance, duration);
                      }//end for j
                    }//end for i
                  }//end if
                }//end callback

                **var theindex = 1;
                function generateArray(origin, destin, dis, dur){
                    places[theindex].distance = dis;
                    places[theindex].duration = dur;
                    theindex++;


            }//end generateTable**
            console.log(places);
```